# JavaScript - Remove object from array when the condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
  var arr = [{"userId":"12j219","name":"Harry"},{"userId":"232j32", "name":"Nancy"}]
```

I want to delete a whole object when the following condition is met:

```
userId == 12j219
```

For that, I've done the following:

```
arr.filter((user)=>{
    if(user.userId != "12j219"){
    return user;
    }
    })
```

It does the job, but for sure it does not delete anything.
How can I delete the object from the array?

Comment: arr = arr.filter(...)

Comment: `filter` returns a new array.

Comment: @Alex nice catch ! it solves the issue, thanks !

Comment: The filter function should return a boolean, not the user. So it could be simplified to `filteredArray = arr.filter(user => user.userId !== '12j219')`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan totally right, will look clean and simplified, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Nope, no JSON here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) returns a new array. From the docs:

> **Return value:** A new array with the elements that pass the test.

You need assign the resultant array to `arr` variable.

Try:

```
var arr = [{"userId":"12j219","name":"Harry"},{"userId":"232j32", "name":"Nancy"}]
arr = arr.filter((user) => {
    return user.userId !== '12j219'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple references to the same array in different places of the code, you can just assign it to itself.

```
arr = arr.filter(user => user.userId !== "12j219");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically array filter iterates on all the elements from array, expects a true or false return. If false that element is removed and if true it stays.

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(el){
    return el.userId != "12j219";
});
```